# Datetime function has stopped working

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting an error from my Python script - not sure if it because there's an issue with the date being passed to it, or because I'm using the wrong method from the imported datetime module.

**Code**

```
import webapp2
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import users

import db
import shift_calendar
import templates
import authenticate


def is_BST(input_date):
    if input_date.month in range(4,9):
        return True
    if input_date.month in [11,12,1,2]:
        return False
    # Find start and end dates for current year
    current_year = input_date.year

    for day in range(25,32):
        if datetime.datetime(current_year,3,day).weekday()==6:
            BST_start = datetime.datetime(current_year,3,day,1)
        if datetime.datetime(current_year,10,day).weekday()==6:
            BST_end = datetime.datetime(current_year,10,day,1)

    if (input_date > BST_start) and (input_date < BST_end):
        return True

    return False
```

**Error**

```
  if datetime.datetime(current_year,3,day).weekday()==6:
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

**Addendum**

The function that is passing datetime.now() to the above script is this:

```
if is_BST(datetime.now()) == True:
    displaytime = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    today = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    starthour = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%H')
    timenow = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%H')
    endhour = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=2)).strftime('%H')
else:
    displaytime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    starthour = datetime.now().strftime('%H')
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    timenow = datetime.now().strftime('%H')
    endhour = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%H')
```

Comment: it would be nice if whoever downvoted this had left a comment to suggest an improvement (I did look at a related question but I wasn't sure if I was getting the error for the same reason)

Comment: plus the fact that it was working previously, and then suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `datetime` from `datetime` already, so there is no need to call `datetime.datetime` in your code.

Either change your import statement to `import datetime` or change your code to `datetime(...)`.

By the way, you might want to look into using [`arrow`](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of `datetime` as well.

```
for day in range(25, 32):
    if datetime(current_year, 3, day).weekday() == 6:
        BST_start = datetime(current_year, 3, day, 1)
    if datetime(current_year, 10, day).weekday() == 6:
        BST_end = datetime(current_year, 10, day, 1)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :-)

Comment: Hehe. Yes, this site can be really extremely fast sometimes, it's incredible. I'm pretty new here, but I'm enjoying it.

Wait, this should go into meta or something, right? :-)

Comment: that worked a treat, thanks! You were so fast that I can't accept the answer for another eight minutes :)